# Separating two huge images into two pages

Tags: floats, line-breaking, subfloats

How can I seperate two huge images into two pages? I tried `\newline` but no success.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
%\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=435pt]{img-molmicros2.png}
}
\newline
\subfloat{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=451pt]{img-molmicros3.png}
}
\caption{sdfsdfsdf}
\label{fgdfg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you use `subfloat` TeX will place the figures at a place where it 'thinks' they are suitable, this might be on one single page. `\newline` is of no use here.

Answer (score 4):

They should be inside separate `figure` environments like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=435pt]{example-image-a}
}
\caption{sdfsdfsdf}\label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=451pt]{example-image-b}
}
\caption{sdfsdfsdf}
\label{fgdfg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]